# Python: How to convert ndarray to ndarray list

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to extract first axis of `numpy.ndarray` to become a list of `numpy.ndarray`.

For example, `arr_A` contains a numpy ndarray with shape (3, 100, 200) which will be converted to a list of numpy ndarray with shape (100, 200) and `len(arr_A)` is 3.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass the `ndarray` to the constructor of `list`:

```
list_arr_A = list(arr_A)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_arr_A = [m for m in arr_A]
```